# Optical sensor without lense,how would pictures look like?

Tags: optics

How would image taken with flat rectangular cmos/ccd optical sensor,the type that is found in digital cameras,look like if there was no lenses in front of it?

I know that lenses are used for zoom,but if I didnt need any magnification,would lenseless sensor be unusable? Would the picture it takes look bad?

Answer (score 1):

You have no image plane and so you would have no image. It would all just be a blur.

Answer (score 0):

Without lens the image would be an indistinguishable blur, because rays of light from many different objects would hit the same point of the sensor. You can get the idea by bringing brightly-colored object near matt-white wall and looking at dim spots of colors on the wall.

Lens aren't just for magnification, they are also used to adjust focus. That is, they bring all light radiating from single point of the object (and passing through the lens) into single point on the sensor.

Though you can try to build a [camera obscura](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camera_obscura) without lens using small aperture of the diaphragm, assuming you allow its usage.